# I have data in json format and I want to make tables for a document, sorting by one of the elements in the data

Tags: json

I have a data dump. It's in Json format. Can I sort the data on the client side and make a document listing the information for a manager to read?

I'd like to sort by "status" and then have the remaining fields in a readable format.

This is a sample of the data.
{
"name":"KEY",
"first_name”:”Barney”,
"last_name”:”Rubble”,
"status”:”Ongoing”,
“Description”:”current task ongoing, need resolution soon.”
}

Edit: I should have added that the output should look like this (Assuming Ongoing and Complete are statuses):

Ongoing
-Barney Rubble - current task ongoing, need resolution soon

Complete
-Wilma Flintstone - touch base in two months

Comment: Don't worry if you're new at this - not something you need to add. But... you probably want to edit your question to show what you've done so far, vs. just asking an open-ended question like this (which sounds like "can you write this for me please"). Also: we have no idea what format is required for a "manager to read." That can mean pretty much anything.

Comment: Unfortunately high end code is not my skill. I do IT and some industrial, low level programming. I know that this is in Json and I know that there are many paths to the goal. I would appreciate a beginning direction (Pyhon, PHP, Jquery, etc)

Answer (score -1):

The [JQ program](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) is a lovely tool for stream-processing JSON documents.  It can filter, edit, sort JSON inputs and produce JSON output (for piping) or other formats.

From [its manual](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#example40) sort thusly:

```
        % jq 'sort_by(.foo)' input.json
Input   [{"foo":4, "bar":10}, {"foo":3, "bar":100}, {"foo":2, "bar":1}]
Output  [{"foo":2, "bar":1}, {"foo":3, "bar":100}, {"foo":4, "bar":10}]
```